# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

When I am generating scripts for my database it fails. The database is of 60gb and it fails somewhere 10GB.

Taking backup is not an option as I have connected to remote and remote server does not have enough space.

Below is the error, The error is too long so i have just paste the first few lines([He has the same problem I guess](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1800160-146-1.aspx)):

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptPublishException:
>   An error occurred while scripting the objects. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait
>   operation timed out --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)

As a solution to above link I tried Scripting only Data and then Only Schema which also didn't work in my case.

Comment: Taking backups is the only option if you want to take *backups* and hope to be able to recover if something happens. Scripting is never an option. It's not backup, it's just **scripting**. Fix whatever issues prevent you from taking backups. `remote server doesn't have enough space`. Add space. Take compressed backups - backup compression *is* available in 2017 Standard and up. Or add a remote drive, or a network drive. Backup to *Azure*, which *is* an option

Comment: In any case, this isn't a programming question. It's suitable for `dba.stackexchange.com`. The answer will be the same though

Comment: If the remote server doesn't have enough local storage for backups, consider backing up to a remote share that does.

Comment: Read the answers to the link you provided too. *DON'T* script the data. If you want to move data, script the objects and move the data. The Import Wizard in SSMS does exactly that and allows you to save the package it creates for later execution. It reads the data from one server/source and writes them to another as they arrive. This will be a *slow* process though. It doesn't offer you any safety either. It's not a *backup*.

Comment: To avoid downloading everything each time you'll have to find ways to detect modified data, eg my enabling change tracking on *all* tables. Or you can set up replication between the remote and the local server. You'd still need backups for disaster recovery.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I could try that, Thanks